# Master Quest - Does it reinforce the temple order?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

All of this is necessarily excluding someone just going into a temple for the item and leaving immediately without beating it.

The vanilla Ocarina of Time gives you some choice after the Forest Temple. You can do the Fire Temple and Water Temple in either order. Then, after you've done both of those, you can do the Spirit and Shadow Temples in either order.

Does Master Quest change or limit this freedom? Like, does the redesigned Spirit Temple have anywhere that explicitly requires the Hover Boots? Or, likewise for the Shadow Temple and the Silver Gauntlets, Water Temple and Megaton Hammer, or Fire Temple and Longshot?

Comment: You could really do them in the order you mentioned? *my childhood is a lie*

Comment: Yeah. There's nothing stopping you. There's also a small glitch to do Jabu Jabu's Belly before Dodongo's Cavern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I went to the dungeon walkthroughs of zeldadungeon.net, and did some simple text searches:

- I don't see any references to the Longshot in [the Fire Temple](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda05-ocarina-of-time-master-quest-walkthrough-05.php).
- I don't see any references to the Megaton Hammer in [the Water Temple](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda05-ocarina-of-time-master-quest-walkthrough-07.php) (or [the Ice Cavern](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda05-ocarina-of-time-master-quest-walkthrough-06.php)).
- I don't see any references to the Silver Gauntlets in [the Shadow Temple](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda05-ocarina-of-time-master-quest-walkthrough-09.php).
- I don't see any references to the Hover Boots in [the Spirit Temple](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda05-ocarina-of-time-master-quest-walkthrough-10.php).

This makes sense to me; while they can redesign puzzles, they can't/didn't change the fundamental rooms at all, so finding new places to stuff huge blocks/large gaps would be challenging. (The only possibility then would be adding hammer switches, but I'm not seeing any.)

I'll say you're pretty much good for either order.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little research into the subject, what I can say is that... the fairy bow is not needed to get through the water temple or fire temple to the boss, it might be needed for certain rooms but it doesn't seem like its needed to get to the boss. so in essence you could go Fire, forest, water. Water, fire Forest. Forest, water, Fire. any order you want for the first three or the last two.

I just know that you need to complete the forest temple in order to become child link and forest, water, and fire in order to get the cinema in kakariko village to learn the song to go to the shadow temple, though from my understanding the only thing needed to get through the spirit temple really is the longshot, if you can remember the path the ghost takes through the Desert. Of course now that i think about it, spirit can't be done before the forest temple as you need to be able to do the first half as child link...

I would also like to point out that i could be wrong on some of these.

it takes a bit of working around and doing unorthodox things in the water temple to complete it without the bow. but it is technically possible.

Comment: You mentioned research. Can you link to sources?